# Run scheduled batch in sandbox to change data in production

Tags: apex, sandbox, schedulebatch, production

I have to run a scheduled batch class in a sandbox to update records in production. Please let me know if that is possible some way.

I can't create the batch class in production due to some business restrictions.

Comment: yes, if your batch job do some callouts to production, which update data

Comment: Can you please show me an example of such a case?

Comment: What happens if someone accidentally refreshes the sandbox?

Answer (score 1):

Well that certainly is a complicated situation but sticking to your question, I think your best bet would be to make the batch use the SF API, just as @kurunve said.

Make the batch with the logic you need and then, wherever you're supposed to do a `Database.update(myrecords)`, then make a callout to Production enviroment.

**[Here](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/REST_API)** you can find extense documentation for the REST API.

**[Here](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/modules/apex_integration_services/units/apex_integration_rest_callouts)** you can find a trailhead that guides you through the process of making such a callout.

Take into account that you will have to register the endpoint which you will callout to in `Setup > Remote Site Settings`.